# Using data.table to group events based on criteria using r

Tags: r, if-statement, grouping, data.table

I would like to group data based on certain criteria using R. Basically I have a list of events that I would like to divide, based on a certain pattern of activity, seen in adjacent rows.

```
No.      ID        DATE_EVENT   TIME_EVENT    EVENT   CODE
102995   018159871 07/08/2014   09:01:57      9008    1111
20398    018159871 07/08/2014   09:01:58      1000    1402
105541   018159871 07/08/2014   09:01:58      9210    1111
63492    018253609 07/08/2014   09:54:26      9008    905
37552    018253609 07/08/2014   09:54:45      9008    1111
9627     018253609 07/08/2014   09:54:48      9210    1111
112700   018253609 07/08/2014   09:54:48      1000    1402
50555    018253609 07/08/2014   09:55:56      1000    1401
63634    018253609 07/08/2014   09:55:56      9210    1111 
34551    018330948 07/08/2014   09:21:51      9008    905
47252    018330948 07/08/2014   09:22:15      9008    1111
3975     018330948 07/08/2014   09:22:17      1000    1402
24196    018330948 07/08/2014   09:22:17      9210    1111
111150   018342571 07/08/2014   09:40:08      9008    905
17119    018342571 07/08/2014   09:40:19      9008    1111
18658    018342571 07/08/2014   09:40:21      9210    1111
25654    018342571 07/08/2014   09:40:21      1000    1402
```

I would like to group the data so that 9008 & 905 in one row, followed by a 9008 & 1111 in the next row signifies the start of a new grouping. (As you can see above, when these codes appear, it is at the start of a new ID, however this isn't always the case and that is why this is necessary)

With the help given below, I am currently using the following

```
dt[, NEXT_EVENT:=c(tail(EVENT, -1), NA)]
dt[, NEXT_CODE:=c(tail(CODE, -1), NA)]
dt[(EVENT=="9008" & CODE=="905") &
      (NEXT_EVENT=="9008" & NEXT_CODE=="1111"), 
   list(count = .N)]
```

What this gives me are 2 new columns, each with the following `EVENT and`CODE` in them respectively.

Having looked at my requirements, what I actually need is to be able to group together rows, based on a collection of (or combination of a collection of) `EVENTS`. For example, I would like to be able to group together all the rows that have either `9008` `9009` or `9010` or say all those that have `EVENT` `1000`, or any combination.

Comment: Please post directly executable code when asking questions on SO. You could have used e.g. 'dput' for pasting your data here. Your "code sample" is not complete and using different names compared to the above data. (What are "EVENT_TYPE" and "loginprocess"?) This saves the time of potential answerers and in doing so increases the chance of somebody actually answering your question.

Comment: Thank you @jhin I am gradually coming to understand the wonderful levels of quality expected in questioning on this site. Apologies if I still seem a little sloppy

Comment: There is a problem with data reading in. It can be seen from your last output. Check the code for data reading from CSV file. And test if data has been red in correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a `data.table` solution. Assuming the above data lives in a `data.frame` named `df`:

```
dt <- data.table(df)
# dt[<filter>, <do something>, by=<group>]
dt[, NEXT_EVENT:=c(tail(EVENT, -1), NA)]
dt[, NEXT_CODE:=c(tail(CODE, -1), NA)]
dt[(EVENT=="9008" & CODE=="905") &
      (NEXT_EVENT=="9008" & NEXT_CODE=="1111"), 
   list(count = .N)] # replace this with whatever you want to do with the data
```

You could do the `NEXT_EVENT` and `NEXT_CODE` indexing directly in the main statement, I separated to make them more readable.

Also, if you care about lots of different combinations, you could do something along the lines of:

```
dt[, 
   list(count = .N),
   by=c("EVENT", "CODE", "NEXT_EVENT", "NEXT_CODE")]
```

There are probably ways to do similar things using `plyr` or `dplyr`, but I don't use those packages as much.

---

### After question update

I am able to run the everything without issue. I get a result of

```
dt[(EVENT=="9008" & CODE=="905") &
     (NEXT_EVENT=="9008" & NEXT_CODE=="1111"), 
   list(count = .N)]

   count
1:     3
```

I removed the commas when loading, but cast EVENT and CODE as character columns. I would expect you to get a result of

```
   count
1:     0
```

since you are (I think) comparing "9,008" to "9008" (both as strings).

As a sanity check, here is what the test `data.table` I used ended up looking like (immediately prior to executing the last call that prints results)

```
> dt
        No       ID DATE_EVENT TIME_EVENT EVENT CODE NEXT_EVENT NEXT_CODE
 1: 102995 18159871 07/08/2014   09:01:57  9008 1111       1000      1402
 2:  20398 18159871 07/08/2014   09:01:58  1000 1402       9210      1111
 3: 105541 18159871 07/08/2014   09:01:58  9210 1111       9008       905
 4:  63492 18253609 07/08/2014   09:54:26  9008  905       9008      1111
 5:  37552 18253609 07/08/2014   09:54:45  9008 1111       9210      1111
 6:   9627 18253609 07/08/2014   09:54:48  9210 1111       1000      1402
 7: 112700 18253609 07/08/2014   09:54:48  1000 1402       1000      1401
 8:  50555 18253609 07/08/2014   09:55:56  1000 1401       9210      1111
 9:  63634 18253609 07/08/2014   09:55:56  9210 1111       9008       905
10:  34551 18330948 07/08/2014   09:21:51  9008  905       9008      1111
11:  47252 18330948 07/08/2014   09:22:15  9008 1111       1000      1402
12:   3975 18330948 07/08/2014   09:22:17  1000 1402       9210      1111
13:  24196 18330948 07/08/2014   09:22:17  9210 1111       9008       905
14: 111150 18342571 07/08/2014   09:40:08  9008  905       9008      1111
15:  17119 18342571 07/08/2014   09:40:19  9008 1111       9210      1111
16:  18658 18342571 07/08/2014   09:40:21  9210 1111       1000      1402
17:  25654 18342571 07/08/2014   09:40:21  1000 1402         NA        NA
```

---

### After question update #2

I'm not sure `data.table` was designed for your new requirements. You can make it work using the code below, but it isn't terribly elegant.

```
dt[,SEQUENCE:=1:.N]
dt[EVENT==9008 & CODE==905 & 
     NEXT_EVENT==9008 & NEXT_CODE==1111, 
   GRP_ID:=1:.N]
if (is.na(dt[1, GRP_ID]))
  dt[1, GRP_ID:=0]
grps <- dt[!is.na(GRP_ID), unique(GRP_ID)]
for (grp in grps) {
  dt[SEQUENCE>max(SEQUENCE[!is.na(GRP_ID) & GRP_ID==grp]) &
       SEQUENCE<min(SEQUENCE[!is.na(GRP_ID) & GRP_ID==grp+1]), 
     GRP_ID:=grp]
}
```

`min` will throw a warning when it gets called for group 4 (which doesn't exist), but it won't break things. Like I said, it's a rather ugly solution. Perhaps others have better ideas.

Comment: You can improve your code, like this `dt[, list(count = .N), by=c("EVENT", "CODE", "NEXT_EVENT", "NEXT_CODE")]`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dt[, NEXT_EVENT:=c(tail(EVENT, -1), NA)]`?

Comment: This looks amazing @Matt. I am just not sure how to use it :-S What do you mean by `<filter>` `<do something>` and `by=<group>`? I then am not sure what you are doing when you actually implement that.

Comment: The `data.table` FAQ is a good intro. See http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf

Comment: Another excellent resource is Matt Dowle's recent [tutorial at useR2014](http://user2014.stat.ucla.edu/files/tutorial_Matt.pdf).

Comment: @Matt @djhurio I have nearly got this working however it is giving me the following error message 
   ` Warning message:
    In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(NEXT_CODE, c(tail(CODE,  :
      Supplied 132931 items to be assigned to 1 items of column     'NEXT_CODE' (132930 unused)`

Comment: Can you update your question with your current implementation and sample data (sanitized is fine) so that answers aren't just guesses as to what you might be doing?

Comment: It looks to me like your `data.table` has some issues before you ever start using the commands I recommended. Check to see if it looks like the one I printed out in my updated answer (minus the NEXT_* columns) and update the post if there are differences.

Comment: @Matt You are correct, there was a problem with the way that I was reading in the data.table I have now fixed that and also the problem with how I was comparing `9,008` with `9008`. You will see that I have now slightly changed my question as I have found that I need to group together more than just what I mentioned previously and it is in fact a group of ID's that I want to group, signified as starting by a group of `EVENT`s

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the expected result: Using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
  df %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(lead), NEXT_EVENT=EVENT, NEXT_CODE=CODE) %>% 
  group_by(EVENT, CODE, NEXT_EVENT, NEXT_CODE) %>%
  tally() 

   #  EVENT CODE NEXT_EVENT NEXT_CODE n
   #1 1,000 1401      9,210      1111 1
   #2 1,000 1402      1,000      1401 1
   #3 1,000 1402      9,210      1111 2
   #4 1,000 1402         NA        NA 1
   #5 9,008  905      9,008      1111 3
   #6 9,008 1111      1,000      1402 2
   #7 9,008 1111      9,210      1111 2
   #8 9,210 1111      1,000      1402 2
   #9 9,210 1111      9,008       905 3
```